# Proving that language is regular or not regular

Tags: regular-language

> Let $L$ be a regular language. Prove that:
>
> 1. $L_{+--}=\left\{w: \exists_u |u|=2|w| \wedge wu\in L\right\}$
> 2. $L_{++-}=\left\{w: \exists_u 2|u|=|w| \wedge wu\in L \right\}$
> 3. $L_{-+-}=\left\{w:\exists_{u,v} |u|=|w|=|v| \wedge uwv\in L\right\}$
>
> are regular and:
>
> 1. $L_{+-+}=\left\{ uv:\exists_w |u|=|w|=|v| \wedge uwv\in L \right\}$
>
> is not regular.

Seems very hard to me. I suppose 1-3 are similar (but I may be wrong), but I don't know how to approach. General idea is usually to modify finite state machine for $L$ to accept other language. But those constructions are often very sophisticated and I still can't come up with it alone.

Comment: Cross-posted at our sister site. Now has an answer here http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/proving-that-language-is-regular-or-not-regular